# Java android set Button on right side

Tags: java, android

I have a linearlayout and inside I have a image button , how I can put image button on the right side ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_vert"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/msg"
    android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you heard  of  `gravity or layout gravity`

Comment: inside ImageButton use this, android:layout_gravity="right|end"

Comment: check my answer. post comment if you face any difficulties

Comment: @Ahamed thanks it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use match_parent to your parent layout, and use gravity = right

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_vert"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:gravity="right|end
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:showDividers="middle">
  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/msg"
    android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make changes accordingly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width=**"match_parent"**
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_vert"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/msg"
    **android:layout_grativty="center_horizontal"**
    android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there is no attribute of ImageButton.android:layout_grativty="center_horizontal"  lol..

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_width="match_parent"` in linear layout. Then put `gravity="end"` in `LinearLayout` to keep the `ImageView` at right side of the page.

This is how the code will be-

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_vert"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/msgs"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```